# Office Interop Exception running Interop v15 on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am running a .exe that i pass an argument to, using Office.Interop v15. It works fine on the dev machine which is windows 7 with Office 2013. When i move to a VM that is running Windows XP and Office 2010, i get a run time error stating

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020005): Type mismatch.    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

Is it because the interop v15 doesn't support a lower version of office?

Snippet where error occurs

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(fileToPrint) /happens here
doc.PrintOut(False)
doc.Close()
app.Quit()
```

Oddly enough it runs but just has a runtime error.

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET?

Comment: Sounds like a 64 bit vs 32 bit error.

Comment: i highly suspect that v15 is not supported or has changed enough to not work properly on XP-supported office versions.

Comment: could you provide the code snippet where the error occurs?

Comment: Microsoft has managed to the Office Automation object model going without drastic breakage for over 15 years now.  An incredible accomplishment.  But yes, it is starting to show cracks at the seams with version 15.  I suspect a "Project Spartan" is going to happen for Office soon as well.  You can't get help if you don't show your code.

Comment: Yeah i had the code in there showing where the error occurred however it was editted out. I put it back in

Comment: Here's a hint for posting better questions: if the error happens on the first line, then we don't need the second line (or the third, or the fourth...)

Comment: Another hint: notice how I edited your title. Your title should make someone want to read the question. "VB.NET Office Interop" doesn't accomplish that goal.

Comment: please include if the 32 bit or the 64 bit version of office is installed on windows 7 and the windows xp VM

Comment: 7 is 64 bit Office, xp is 32 bit office

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Replace this code:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(fileToPrint) /happens here
```

With this (in VB.NET)

```
Dim s_missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
doc = app.Documents.Open (fileToPrint, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing,s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing, s_missing)
```

Or with this (in C#)

```
static object s_missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
doc = app.Documents.Open ( ref fileToPrint,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing );
```